# Arduino Android and USB host API

Tags: android, arduino

I have a device linked to the serial port of an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). I need to link the Arduino to an Android smartphone via USB in order to read the data retrieved from the serial port. I was planning to use Android USB host API so the Arduino will act as the USB device.

Is there any library out there to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549) shows how to communicate with Arduino from Nexus.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but I think it would be useful if you added the main points from the linked page into the answer. That way your answer will still be useful if the link dies.